# When running bash script there is a logical error

Tags: bash

So I have fixed my first issue with the script taking input but now no matter what letter I enter it only adds the numbers.

here is the code. any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash

add() {
        expr $x + $y
}

sub() {
        expr $x - $y
}

mult() {
        expr $x * $y
}

div() {
        expr $x / $y
}

 echo "Enter a for add, s for subtract, m for multiply or d for divide and 2 numbers"
read choice x y

 if [ $choice=="a" ]
 then
         add
 else
        if [ $choice == "s" ]
        then
                sub
        else
                if [ $choice == "m" ]
                then
                        mult
                else
                        if [ $choice == "d" ]
                        then
                                div

                        fi
                fi
        fi
fi
```

Comment: "there is no chance for input". Not clear what you mean, you get the idea that your script can be called like `myscript a 3 4` ? That's your input, else you have to add `read x?"Enter x value"` etc someplace in your script. Also `elif` would be better for your 2ndary tests. Better yet use `case $op in a) add ...;; ....; esac` etc. Better to clarify your Q text, than responding in comments. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. I changed from the 2 methods of adding input half way through and got all confused.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you want to get *x* and *y* from first and second arguments ( `$1` and `$2` ) and to read the operation ( *a, s, d, m* ) from stdin.
I modified your code a bit, to overcome the problems in the original script and to provide the result based on my assumptions:

```
#!/bin/bash

# First number.
x=$1
# Second number.
y=$2
# Result of either addition, subtraction, division or multiplication of     $x and $y.
result=0

# Reads operation from user.
read -ep "Enter a for add, s for subtract, m for multiply or d for divide: " operation

case $operation in
    a) result=$(( x + y ));;
    s) result=$(( x - y ));;
    d) result=$(( x / y ));;
    m) result=$(( x * y ));;
    *) printf '%s: %s\n' "$operation" "Unknown operation" >&2; exit 1;;
esac

printf 'result: %s\n' "$result"
```

*Usage example:* ( script name is ***sof.sh*** )

```
./sof.sh 5 4
Enter a for add, s for subtract, m for multiply or d for divide: a
result: 9

./sof.sh 5 4
Enter a for add, s for subtract, m for multiply or d for divide: m
result: 20

./sof.sh 5 4
Enter a for add, s for subtract, m for multiply or d for divide: s
result: 1

./sof.sh 5 4
Enter a for add, s for subtract, m for multiply or d for divide: d
result: 1
```

**P.S.**

Please note the following:

- `expr` is a program used in ancient shell code to do math. In POSIX shells like bash, use `$(( expression ))`. In bash, ksh88+, mksh/pdksh, or zsh, you can also use `(( expression ))` or 'let 
              expression'.
- Though not used originaly in the script, while programming in Bash it is worth knowing that `[[` is a bash keyword similar to (but more powerful than) the `[` command. See this [Bash FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031) and [Test and conditionals](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals).
  Unless you're writing for POSIX sh, it is recommended to use `[[`.

Answer (score 2):

*First* of all, you want the script to [read the values from the standard input](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput#File_Descriptors), but you are recovering it from the arguments.

*Second*, you are not passing parameters to the functions.

*Third*, you are not using parameters inside the functions.

*Fourth*, you are not letting spaces between operators when using **expr**.

**NOTE**:  *Rany Albeg Wein* remarked that this [bash guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_08_02.html) is outdated, and he recommends [this one](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput#File_Descriptors). Also i recommend the [GNU official guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/index.html) ([other formats](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/)).

So, assuming that you want to use your script like `./my-script.sh m 2 3` , here is your code, but working:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                           

add() {                                                                            
    expr $1 + $2                                                                   
}                                                                                  

sub() {                                                                            
    expr $1 - $2                                                                   
}                                                                                  

mult() {                                                                           
    expr $1 \* $2                                                                  
}                                                                                  

div() {                                                                            
    expr $1 / $2                                                                   
}                                                                               

echo "Enter a for add, s for subtract, m for multiply or d for divide and 2 numbers"
x=$2                                                                            
y=$3                                                                            

if [ $1 == "a" ]                                                                
then                                                                            
    add $x $y                                                                   
else                                                                            
    if [ $1 == "s" ]                                                            
    then                                                                        
        sub $x $y                                                               
    else                                                                        
        if [ $1 == "m" ]                                                        
        then                                                                    
            mult $x $y                                                          
        else                                                                    
            if [ $1 == "d" ]                                                    
            then                                                                
                div $x $y                                                       
            fi                                                                  
        fi                                                                      
    fi                                                                          
fi
```

And finally this is your script minimally modified to [read the data from the standard input](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput#File_Descriptors):

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                     

add() {                                                                         
    echo "Result:"                                                                                                                                                                    
    expr $1 + $2                                                                
}                                                                               

sub() {                                                                         
    echo "Result:"                                                              
    expr $1 - $2                                                                
}                                                                               

mult() {                                                                        
    echo "Result:"                                                              
    expr $1 \* $2                                                               
}                                                                               

div() {                                                                         
    echo "Result:"                                                              
    expr $1 / $2                                                                
}                                                                               

echo "Enter a for add, s for subtract, m for multiply or d for divide and 2 numbers"
read operation                                                                  
echo "Read first parameter"                                                     
read x                                                                          
echo "Read second parameter"                                                    
read y                                                                          

if [ $operation == "a" ]                                                        
then                                                                            
    add $x $y                                                                   
else                                                                            
    if [ $operation == "s" ]                                                    
    then                                                                        
        sub $x $y                                                               
    else                                                                        
        if [ $operation == "m" ]                                                
        then                                                                    
            mult $x $y                                                          
        else                                                                    
            if [ $operation == "d" ]                                            
            then                                                                
                div $x $y                                                       
            fi                                                                  
        fi                                                                      
    fi     
fi
```

Also, if you had some troubles, you could add debugging messages to the script just setting `#!/bin/bash -xv` at the beginning of the script.

Comment: The tldp Bash guide is outdated, and in some cases just plain wrong. Though partially might be correct, it is recommended to avoid using it, especially as a begginer. I recommend using this [Bash Guide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) instead :-)

Comment: Thank you Rany, I edited the response and added a note. The links now redirect the guide that you recommend.  Also I added the GNU Bash official guide link.

Comment: Great! Thank you :-)